# How to retrieve old Path image when we not update c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on update form, my scenario is I don't want to update new image I just want to update only other data then submit when I submit the form "image URL" shows the null value not show the old path of the image.i have tried this code which I am sharing you kindly tell me how to resolve this issue.
Just give the hint of code then I will resolve this.

**Model**

```
  public class ProductViewModel{

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }  

        [NotMapped]  
        public HttpPostedFileBase imageUpload { get; set; }  

        public ProductViewModel()  
        {  
            ImageUrl = "~/Scripts/imageloading/image.jpg";  
        }  
}
```

**c#**

```
  public ActionResult AddOrEditProducts(ProductViewModel prod)  
           {  
               Product pro = new Product();  
               ProductDetail p_spec = new ProductDetail();  
               var result = new jsonMessage();  
               try  
               {  
                   List<ProductType> PTlist = _IproductType.PTList();  
                   ViewBag.Ptlist = new SelectList(PTlist, "PType_ID", "P_Name");  

                   //Product Color List  
                   List<P_Color> pColorList = _IProductColor.PColorlist();  
                   ViewBag.pColor_List = new SelectList(pColorList, "C_ID", "C_Name_OR_Code");  

                   List<P_Size> pSizeList = _ISize.pSizeList();  
                   ViewBag.pSizeLists = new SelectList(pSizeList, "S_ID", "S_Size");  

                   if (prod.imageUpload != null)  // shows null here
                   {  
                           string filename = Path.GetFileName(prod.imageUpload.FileName);  
                           string _filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssff") + filename;  
                           string extension = Path.GetExtension(prod.imageUpload.FileName);  
                           prod.ImageUrl= "~/upload/" + _filename;  
                       if (extension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || extension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || extension.ToLower() == ".png")  
                           {  
                               if (prod.imageUpload.ContentLength <= 1000000)  
                               {  
                                   prod.imageUpload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/upload/"), _filename));
                                   p_spec = new ProductDetail();  
                                   p_spec.ProductID = prod.ProductID;  
                                   p_spec.OS = prod.OS.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.DualSim = prod.DualSim.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.Camera = prod.Camera.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.TouchScreen = prod.TouchScreen.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.ScreenSize = prod.ScreenSize.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.ProcessorType = prod.ProcessorType.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.RAM = prod.RAM.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.InternalMemory = prod.InternalMemory.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.Wifi = prod.Wifi.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.BatteryLife = prod.BatteryLife.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.Other = prod.Other.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.PDescription = prod.PDescription.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.Model = prod.Model.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.Condition = prod.Condition.Trim();  
                                   p_spec.Discount = prod.Discount;  
                                   p_spec.ImageUrl = prod.ImageUrl;  

                               }  
                               else  
                                   ViewBag.sizemsg = "Size Limit accessed ";  
                           }  
                           else  
                               ViewBag.fileformat = "File is not Format is not Correct";  

                       pro = new Product();  
                       pro.ProductID = prod.ProductID;  
                       pro.PName = prod.PName.Trim();  
                       pro.ManificturedPrice = prod.ManificturedPrice;  
                       pro.P_SizeID = prod.P_SizeID;  
                       pro.P_Color_ID = prod.P_Color_ID;  
                       pro.PType_ID = prod.PType_ID;  
                       pro.UnitWeight = prod.UnitWeight;  
                       pro.UnitInStock = prod.UnitInStock;  
                   }  

                   if (prod.ProductID == 0)  
                   {  
                       _IProducts.AddOrEditProducts(pro, p_spec);  
                       result.Message= "Product has been saved success..";  
                       result.Status = true;  
                       ModelState.Clear();  
                   }  
                   else  
                   {  
                       _IProducts.AddOrEditProducts(pro, p_spec);  
                       result.Message = "Product Update Successfully";  
                       result.Status = true;  
                       ModelState.Clear();  
                   }  
               }  
               catch (DbEntityValidationException e)  
               {  
                   foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)  
                   {  
                       Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",  
                           eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);  
                       foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)  
                       {  
                           Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",  
                               ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);  
                       }  
                       result.Message = "We are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later.";  
                       result.Status = false;  
                   }  
               }  
               return RedirectToAction("ProductsList");  
           }
```

**View**

```
<div id="tabimage" class="tab-pane">  
                           <h3 class="mgtp-15 mgbt-xs-20"> Images</h3>  
                           <div class="vd_panel-menu">  

                               <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn vd_btn vd_bg-blue btn-icon btn-sm save-btn  fa fa-save" id="btnSave" />  
                               <button type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn vd_btn vd_bg-blue btn-icon btn-sm save-btn  fa fa-save" id="" />  

                           </div>  
                           <div class="row">  
                               <div class="form-group">  
                                   <label class="control-label col-lg-3 file_upload_label"> <span title="" data-toggle="tooltip" class="label-tooltip" data-original-title="Format JPG, GIF, PNG. Filesize 8.00 MB max."> Add a new image to this product </span> </label>  
                                   <div class="col-lg-9">  
                                       <div class="col-lg-5">  
                                           <span class="btn vd_btn vd_bg-green fileinput-button">  
                                               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> <span>Add files...</span>  
                                               <input type="file" name="imageUpload" multiple id="imageUpload" onchange="ShowimahePreview(this,document.getElementById('previewImage'))" />  
                                           </span>  
                                       </div>  

                                       <div class="col-lg-4">  
                                           <img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImageUrl)" alt="Alternate Text" height="150" weight="" id="previewImage" />  
                                       </div>  

                                   </div>  
                               </div>  


                           </div>  

                       </div>
```

Comment: If you want to be able to update other information when the image is null, then move the code which does that updating out of the `if (prod.imageUpload != null)` block.

Comment: @ADyson, when I click edit button without changing anything, click submit image show null not retrieve the previous image path. How to resolve this issue kindly, please.

Comment: you have to retrieve it from the database instead. I assume you must have saved a record of that path somewhere to associate the image with the product (although I can't see that in your code right now), otherwise it would have been quite pointless to upload the image. But why do you need the previous path? If the image upload is null, just ignore it, and update the other fields instead.

Comment: @ADyson Yes you are right, I am storing image path in database and save image in the folder . adyon if I ignore the image then the previous image will be wasted..kindly review my code suggest me some change it will helpful for me.

Comment: "I ignore the image then the previous image will be wasted"... you mean deleted? Like I said, if it's not a new product, you can either get the previous imageURL from the database and set it again in your new object, or, you can simply remove the line which sets the value (i.e. `p_spec.ImageUrl = prod.ImageUrl`) whenever the uploaded image is null, and ensure the rest of your code doesn't overwrite it by default anyway. I can't see what your `_IProducts.AddOrEditProducts` method does, but presumably you might need to make a change there as well.